# Symfony custom query builder with repository

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem understanding how the symfony query builder works.
I'm trying to build two select where one referencing the other.

FormType:

```
  ->add('citta', EntityType::class,array(
            'class'=>Comuni::class,
            'query_builder'=>function(ComuniRepository $comuniRepository){
                dump ($comuniRepository->selezionaCAP());
                //return $comuniRepository->selezionaCAP();
            },
            'attr'=>array(
                'placeholder'=>'Inserisci qui la città...'
            ),
            'label'=>'Città:'
        ))
        ->add('provincia', EntityType::class,array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Province',
            'choice_label' => function ($province) {
                return $province->getNomeProvincia();
            },
            'attr'=>array(
                'placeholder'=>'Inserisci qui la provincia...'
            ),
            'label'=>'Provincia:'
        ))
```

Comment: There is a bundle for that: https://packagist.org/packages/evercodelab/dependent-select-bundle or you might need to see this https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a query in the 'query_builder' option and return it.
in your case, if you just want all records , formType would be

```
->add('citta', EntityType::class,array(
        'class'=>Comuni::class,
        'query_builder'=>function(ComuniRepository $comuniRepository){
            return $comuniRepository->createQueryBuilder('cr')
            //if you want a specific query
            //then you should use dql functions like the lines below
            ->where('cr.selezionaCAP = :someParameter')
            ->setParameter('someParameter', $someParameter)
            ->orderBy('cr.selezionaCAP', 'ASC');
        },
        'attr'=>array(
            'placeholder'=>'Inserisci qui la città...'
        ),
        'label'=>'Città:'
    ))
```

for more information you could use this link 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder